# Db2 ODBC driver installed on Docker/Alpine Linux

Tags: docker, db2

I have a [Db2 server community edition](https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/db2) running on a Docker container. I have another Docker container with a python program in the same machine that needs to access the Db2 server with ODBC. The python container runs on Alpine Linux.

[This link](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/387577) points to the Db2 ODBC driver to install in Linux. Since it doesn't specify the Linux distribution, does that mean that it is generic and should work on Alpine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can’t use Alpine because it’s based on the musl library.  The Db2 client will only work on a glibc-based distro, so you’ll probably want to build your client from an Ubuntu image.

Comment: Yes, it should. Are you using the ODBC driver directly or are you installing it as part of the Python driver?

Comment: See also https://hub.docker.com/r/frolvlad/alpine-glibc/

Comment: @data_henrik I will do the regular Linux install and then use the ODBC driver with pyodbc